# Prevent .bash_profile from executing when connecting via SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, ubuntu-18.04, autologin

I have several servers running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.  Although it's considered bad practice to auto login, I understand the risks.

I've done the following to auto-login the user:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
```

Then I add the following to the file:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noissue --autologin my_user %I $TERM
Type=idle
```

Then, I edit the following file for the user to be able to automatically start a program:

```
sudo nano /home/my_user/.bash_profile

# Add this to the file:
cd /home/my_user/my_program
sudo ./program
```

This works great on the console when the server starts, however, when I SSH into the server, the same program is started and I don't want that.

The simplest solution is to SSH with a different user but is there a way to prevent the program from running when I SSH in using the same user?

Comment: FYI -- this will be different between `ssh somehost` and `ssh somehost 'command here'` -- only in the former case will `.bash_profile` or `.profile` be activated.

Comment: BTW, in general, `cd` should always be attached to a command that depends on that `cd` being successful with `&&` rather than `;` or with a newline -- otherwise, you can have your `sudo ./program` run in the wrong directory should the `cd` fail.

Comment: You might also consider making it `(cd /home/user/my_program && exec sudo ./program)` -- the parens create a subshell that the `cd` is scoped to, and the `exec` consumes that subshell by replacing it with the `sudo` executable; so the parent shell is still in its original directory, and there's no efficiency decrease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy approach is to check the environment for variables ssh sets; there are several.

```
# only run my_program on login if not connecting via ssh
if [ -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ]; then
  cd /home/my_user/my_program && sudo ./program
fi
```